# How to change the font color of the orderlist when a checkbox is selected?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am developing the list with check and uncheck box for the carlist and list was in array and i am not able change the font color in list using angularjs and html

this is like to do list option page the car list will have yes and no check box but when i tried to check and uncheck it was working for the first object in the list please help me to do the same in the list

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li id="list" ng-repeat="x in cars | orderBy">
   <input type="checkbox" id="selected" ng-model="cars[x]" onchange="changeColor()"/> 
   <input type="checkbox" id="nonSelected" onchange="changeColor()"/>{{x}}</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('orderCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = ["Porsche", "Bentley", "Audi", "Ferrari", "BMW", "Ford"];
});
function changeColor()
{
    if(document.getElementById("nonSelected").checked==true){
        document.getElementById("list").style.color="red";
        document.getElementById("selected").disabled = true;
        return;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("selected").checked==true){
        document.getElementById("list").style.color="green";
        document.getElementById("nonSelected").disabled = true;
        return;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("list").style.color="black";
        document.getElementById("selected").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("nonSelected").disabled = false;
        return;
    }

}
</script>
```

results must be list when i selected the checkbox the list font must change the color and another check box should disabled in the array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using AngularJS in correct way. The problem that your are facing is because of same id of each input for each car. Below is a working code for your problem.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.cars = ["Porsche", "Bentley", "Audi", "Ferrari", "BMW", "Ford"];
$scope.cars.sort();
$scope.car_obj = [];
for (var i=0; i<$scope.cars.length; i++){
    $scope.car_obj.push({name: $scope.cars[i], selected: false, nonSelected: false}) 
}
$scope.getCheckedCount = function(type){
  return $scope.car_obj.filter(function(car){return car[type]}).length;
}
  
});
```

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}

.text-green {
  color: green;
}

.text-black {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>selected: {{getCheckedCount('selected')}}</div>
  <div>nonSelected: {{getCheckedCount('nonSelected')}}</div>

<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li id="list" ng-repeat="x in car_obj">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.selected" ng-disabled="x.nonSelected"/> 
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.nonSelected" ng-disabled="x.selected"/><span ng-class="{'text-red': x.nonSelected, 'text-green': x.selected}">{{x.name}}</span></li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am new to angularjs so i not aware of the concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the help it was working fine and one more hassan can we able to add the count of selected and nonselected.

Comment: can i use like this to get the count of selected and non selected $scope.checkedCount = function(){
      return $scope.car_obj.filter(function(car){
        return car.checked;
      }).length;   this is will use for the single column count for the selected and non selected

Comment: How can i implement the same in the drop box?

Comment: @Prasad you can write your methods in your controller to get count of your checked check box.  Checked updated code.

Comment: What do you want to do in dropdown?

Comment: yes @muhammad i want to do the same concept in the drop down box